# Clear field onButtonClick with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I have two fields : Password and ConfirmPassword,
After the button has been clicked to reset them, after a few seconds I need to clear out that field.

```
   <input tabindex="5" type="password" class="form-control" name="newPsw" [(ngModel)]="newPassword" (ngModelChange)=" checkPassword()">
  <input tabindex="5" type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmPsw" [(ngModel)]="confirmPsw" (ngModelChange)=" checkPassword()">
```

On the component the checkPassword function :

```
       checkPassword() {
         //password validation here 
         //service that makes the change
         this.userService.changePassword(this.currentPassword, this.newPassword, this);

     }
  //response
 changePasswordResult(success: boolean) {
this.passwordUpdated = success;
```

}

if the password has been updated successfully, I need to set a Timeout function that after a few seconds clears out the fields.
Do I put :

```
  if(this.passwordUpdated = true) {
       setTimeout(function() {
        this.newPsw = ''
  },10000 )
}
```

Is this a good practice? How can this be handled?
Thanks.

Comment: Post your code in such a way we can test it... post also error code if you have it.

Comment: This is question might be better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the code change you need:

```
this.passwordUpdated = success;
if (success )
{
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementsByName("newPsw")[0].value = "";
        document.getElementsByName("confirmPsw")[0].value = "";
  },10000 );
}
```